# boost::thread undefined reference

Tags: c++, ubuntu, boost-thread

I just installed the boost libraries and I am trying to use multi - threading. I copied this example exactly from the boost library example. I am getting the error:

`undefined reference boost::thread::join()`

Here is the code,

```
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
#include <boost/thread/xtime.hpp>
#include <iostream>

struct thread_alarm
{
    thread_alarm(int secs) : m_secs(secs) { }
    void operator()()
    {
        boost::xtime xt;
        boost::xtime_get(&xt, boost::TIME_UTC);
        xt.sec += m_secs;

        boost::thread::sleep(xt);

        std::cout << "alarm sounded..." << std::endl;
    }

    int m_secs;
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int secs = 5;
    std::cout << "setting alarm for 5 seconds..." << std::endl;
    thread_alarm alarm(secs);
    boost::thread thrd(alarm);
    thrd.join();
}
```

Comment: Does the beginning of your error message say "ld" ? It sounds like you just have not built Boost. (I believe `boost::thread` is one of the libraries that needs to be built first). Alternately, use `std::thread` instead given that GCC supports that C++0x feature IIRC.

Comment: thread is not a member of std

Comment: And boost not being built, i thought might be an issue. But @ http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/more/getting_started/unix-variants.html it says thread must be built and then on the next page http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/doc/html/thread.html it says that I just have to include the master header file. So I am not sure what to do.

Comment: In C++0x, thread *is* a member of `std`. (You might need to specify `--std=c++0x` in order to get it in G++)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

which compiler?

try this if it is gcc

```
$ g++ -o ./app.out ./source.cpp -lboost_thread
```

if you are running on windows, perhaps that you have to make sure that the pthread you have installed, and also you have to tell the compiler where and how to link them together, your application and 3rd party lib such as `boost_thread`.

hope this is useful for you

Answer (score 1):

Under my Fedora Core 16, the required boost lib to link against was 'boost_thread-mt' (add '-lboost_thread-mt' to your linker cocktail.